# Popup blocked when created in jQuery ajax success callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, popup

Google Chrome seems to be blocking a popup I am creating via jQuery. After some investigation, it appears to be an issue with calling `window.open` in the success event of an ajax call. Is there a way around this? My jQuery ajax call returns the URL to be opened. So I am bit stuck.

It works if I place the `window.open` outside the ajax call; but, inside (i.e. in the success event) it is blocked. I think it is something to do with CONTEXT but I am unsure.

Here is what I have:

```
     window.open("https://www.myurl.com");  // OUTSIDE OF AJAX - no problems 
                                            // with popup

     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MyService.aspx/ConstructUrl",
        data: jsonData,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            // Normally loads msg.d which is the url returned from service
            // static url below is for testing
            window.open("https://www.myurl.com");  // THIS IS BLOCKED
        },
        error: function(msg) {
            // alert(error);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply open the new window in the success callback:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MyService.aspx/ConstructUrl",
    data: jsonData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        window.open("https://www.myurl.com"); 
    },
    error: function(msg) {
        //alert(error);
    }
});
```

Note you might have to set $.ajax's async option to false for that, otherwise the code following the $.ajax call could be evaluated before the response is received.

Comment: karim, you just saved my day!

Comment: What's the use of AJAX (which after all means 'Asynchronous Javascript And Xml') when you're not using it asynchronous? There are several alternatives, like using a modal, opening the window before the request, showing a load text, and redirecting the window on completion. I think this is quite dirty.

Comment: @pst - Good lord. I was young back then. I will fix this.

Comment: You're welcome .. I'm just saved that nobody reads my old answers ^^

Comment: @karim79 I think now the code in the question and in your answer are identical. I have the same problem and can't get it to work properly too: if window.open is used in the "success" callback, it gets blocked by browsers.

Comment: @parrker9 if you look at the edit history you can see that there was a note about the async flag being set to false. in it's current state the answer is useless, imho

Comment: $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "POST",

Answer (score 19):

As several people have pointed out, the accepted answer no longer works.  Based on the comment by aidiakapi, I used a workaround by first opening the window.

```
window.open("about:blank", "myNewPage");
```

Then doing the ajax business and in the `done()` function, open the page with that name.

```
window.open("/foo.html", "myNewPage");
```

This also doesn't matter if you do it async or not.

Comment: This works for me in the latest versions of Safari, Chrome and Firefox. It should be the accepted answer.

Comment: [Another way that seems to work well.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16361814/98069)

Comment: This won't work if you need to open a new window conditionally on what you get back in the data. In our case we should only open a new tab if we find a certain value in our JSON object that we get back. With this approach, we would be opening/closing windows.

Comment: @geneb. The answer for you is simple: you can't.  If you open a window without a user action, it will be blocked by the browser.  This workaround works because it opens the window on the user action.  You need to add a user action.  So the best you can do is wait for your JSON, then display a "ready" button for the user to click.

Comment: Working great! Life saving answer. :)

Answer (score 7):

Your code returns these in firefox and chrome:

Firefox: "Firefox prevented this site from opening a pop-up window."
Chrome: "Pop-up blocked"

To fix this issue just add async:false to your ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
async: false,
url: "MyService.aspx/ConstructUrl",
data: jsonData,
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function(url) {
    window.open(url); 
},
error: function(msg) {
    //alert(error);
}
```

});

Just be careful that async:false will force javascript to wait for jQuery ajax result. It means it freezes javascript until ajax call is completed.

Comment: FYI this does not work anymore with Chrome Version 30 or IE 10.0.4

Comment: Locking up the UI seems to be a bad plan in most cases.

Comment: Since we are redirecting to another page after ajax call, then it wouldn't be a big issue.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox does popup blocking based on the event that causes the javascript code to run; e.g., it will allow a popup to open that was triggered from an `onclick`, but not one that was triggered by a `setTimeout`.  It has gotten a little bit complicated over the years as advertisers have tried to circumvent firefox's popup blocker.

Answer (score 1):

You can still have the code in the success event but async will need to be false.

Comment: Locking up the UI seems to be a bad plan in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the method described in this post:

[window.open without popup blocker using AJAX and manipulating the window.location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361813/window-open-without-popup-blocker-using-ajax-and-manipulating-the-window-locatio/16361814#16361814)

In a nutshell, the approach is:

1. Your code must be initiated by an `onclick` event.
2. Open a new window, perhaps initially with no content, with `window.open` --- and store a reference to the window so that you can use it later.
3. In the success callback from your AJAX operation, use `window.location.replace` to manipulate the URL of your already-open window with the desired URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if you put async:true then you must do the following:

 var safariOP = window.open("https://www.myurl.com");  // DEFINE BEFORE AJAX CALLBACK 

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MyService.aspx/ConstructUrl",
    data: jsonData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
      if(safariOP){
         safariOP.focus(); // IT'S OK ON SAFARI
      }
    },
    error: function(msg) {
        //alert(error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you put async:true then you must do the following:

```
var safariOp = window.open("https://www.myurl.com"); //define before callback ajax contains url .
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MyService.aspx/ConstructUrl",
    data: jsonData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        //it's ok on safari
        safariOp.focus();
    },
    error: function(msg) {
        //alert(error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myLink').on( "click", function() {
            var myNewTab = window.open('about:blank', '_blank');
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" },
            })
            .done(function( msg ) {
                myNewTab.location.href = "google.com";
            });
        });
    });
```